# REGEX Matching with Exceptions (for CSS)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace some CSS style with PHP.

I want to add `.myclass` in front of all `#` and `.` after any `,`
but not those lines start with `background` and with ';' at the end.

So far, my regex is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my PHP:

```
$patterns = '/^[^background][,]\s*((#|[.])[^;]+)/m';
$replacements = ', .myclass \1';
$str= preg_replace($patterns,$replacements, $string, -1);
```

Here is the original CSS:

```
#class1, #id1, #id2{
    margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
    font-size:2.2em;
    font-family:Century Schoolbook Bold;
}
.class2{
    background:#fff, #111, #ccc;
    font:1.1em;
    font-family:Century Schoolbook;
}
```

And here is the desired CSS:

```
#class1, .myclass #id1, .myclass #id2{
        margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
        font-size:2.2em;
        font-family:Century Schoolbook Bold;
    }
    .class2{
            background:#fff, #111, #ccc;
        font:1.1em;
        font-family:Century Schoolbook;
    }
```

Comment: You want to add `.myclass` in front of *all* `#` and `.`, then how come `#class1` and `.class2` stay the same? And under those rules `font-size:2.2em;` would turn into `font-size:2.myclass2em;` (add `myclass` after `.`). Could you clarify your question please/narrow your criteria for what exactly must be replaced?

Comment: e.g. "I want to add `.myclass` after every `#` and `.` that occur *on a line ending with* `{`" ? (which still doesn't explain why `#class1` and `.class2` didn't get changed)

Comment: sorry i meant i want to add .myclass in front of '#' and ',' only after the comma, thanks for looking into it man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[blah] is a character class, which means it will match any of those letters; so [^background] means match any char that is in that word.  Similarly, you don't need a char class to match a single character such as a comma.

Edit: since php doesn't support variable length lookbehind, loop over each line, and skip those that start with background:

```
foreach($lines as $line){
   if(preg_match("/^\s*background.+\;$/",$line) == 0)
   {
      array_push($new, preg_replace("/,\s+#/",", .myclass ",$line));
   }
   else
   {
      array_push($new,$line);
   }
}
```

Or similar.

Comment: No, it will not work, because you need variable length look-behind assertion and it is not implemented.

Comment: ah, you're right.  also I'm mixing in some perl syntax.  Must edit.

Comment: what is the '?' and '!' inside (?<!\s*background), 
and /g ? mmm ... i should look into it, thanks man !

Comment: Check out details on assertions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it is impossible to solve your task wit one regular expression.
You need variable length look-behind assertions to solve it and they are not implemented.
But if they were, the solution would look like:

```
/(?<!background:.*)(#[a-zA-Z_0-9]*)/
```

The problem here is with `(?<!background:.*)`. You say `.*`, that means that this assertion can have any length. And it will work work anymore.

The much simpler solution is to split the task into two parts.

1. Check line for `background` inside.
2. If there are no `background`, run `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

"Add `.myclass` in front of '#' and ',' only after the comma" --> so you want to add `.myclass` in between `,` and `#`?

i.e. whenever you see `, #` you want it to be `, .myclass #` ?

And I'm guessing you only want to affect lines that define the CSS classes (which is why you exclude `background: ...`).

In that case, I'd suggest the following criteria:

"Whenever you see `,[space]#`, turn it in to `, .myclass #` **only if** the line on which this occurs **ends in a `{`**." (or perhaps "only if the line on which this occurs does not end in a `;`").

This relies on the fact that when you make CSS selectors you end the line with a `{` and these are the only lines you wish to affect.

Then I'd suggest replacing regex:

```
/, *#(?=.+\{ *$)/m
```

with :

```
', .myclass #'
```

How this works:

```
, *#    : "find a comma followed by 0 or more spaces and then a hash symbol,
(?=     : FOLLOWED BY:
  .+    : the rest of the line PLUS
  \{ *$): an opening curly bracket at the end of the line (possibly spaces between this and the end of the line)
```

The `/m` means that if `$string` contains new lines, `$` matches the end of a line (as opposed to the end of the entire string `$string`).

In terms of fine-tuning the regex, have a play around [here](http://regexr.com?31k9b) (i.e. verify that your regex works *first*, *then* try it in PHP, so that if you have any problems you will know whether it's a regex problem or a PHP problem).